# IE7 - Randomly Disappearing Elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

When looking at this [site](http://steamsaunadepot.com/) in IE7, the header banners and nav menu seem to randomly appear and disappear. Have look at several posts regarding this, but have not been able to solve it. I am hopeful someone could help pinpoint the issue, as the page appears correct at times, and not at most others.

Thanks.

Comment: Get Chrome, Firefox 8, Safari, Opera, or at least IE9?

Comment: @fabianhjr I'm not doing this for myself. this is to ensure compatibility for users who are using IE7 and don't care to upgrade, or are entirely oblivious of that fact.

Comment: Move the submenu a little higher, there is a small gap that makes it collapse, or ask them to move their mouse faster.

Answer (score 2):

You are using two separate style sheets.
http://steamsaunadepot.com/media/css/cb5ec47641853ec8a1ca38b845e6e92e.css is for FF and
http://steamsaunadepot.com/media/css/36fe96c008dc78bed45bceb2c9cde999.css is for IE7

Specifically, the styles for top and left on .header-notice and .header-banner are wrong in IE7.  If they were just set the same as they are in FF, the header and footer generates correctly.

Comment: i have just implemented your solution.it fixes things on some pages, although most product pages, or the contact us page still results in in improper placement, although all elements are rendered.